# My cplex logical constraint is not working with no error

Tags: python-3.x, cplex

I am new with cplex python. I have a model with different constraints that all work fine except for my if-then constraint. x is a binary variable.
my constraint explanation is

"if x[i,j,t1] == 1 (for t in the range of T ) then all the x[j,i,t2]== 0 for t2 in[t+1 ,t+2,t+3 ]".

My code:

```
        for i in I:
            for j in J:
              for t in T:
                mdl.add_constraint(mdl.if_then(x[i,j,t]==1, x[j,i,t+1]+x[j,i,t+2]+y[j,i,t+3]==0))
```

After solving the model, the solution is breaking this rule. There's no error regarding this issue so I can not understand what part I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to understand what is happening is display all the boolean values of the if then.

For example I can rewrite the ifthen example from [this file](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooifthen.py) into

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
   print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print()
print("with if nb buses 40 more than 3  then nbBuses30 more than 7")

#if then constraint
mdl.add(mdl.if_then(nbbus40>=3,nbbus30>=7))
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

print("if ",nbbus40.solution_value>=3)
print("then ",nbbus30.solution_value>=7)


for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

which gives

```
with if nb buses 40 more than 3  then nbBuses30 more than 7
if  False
then  True
```

which helps to understand what is happening.